# bootclasspathref in Android SDK r20

Tags: android, ant, sdk

I have just upgraded from the Andriod SDK r19 to r20. When I attempt to build my project with r20 I get the error:

Reference android.target.classpath not found.

The build.xml fragment is:

```
`<javac source="${java.source}" target="${java.target}"
debug="true" extdirs=""
destdir="${native.classes.dir}"
bootclasspathref="android.target.classpath"
verbose="${verbose}">
<src path="${src.dir}" />
<include name="DifferentTouchInput.java"/>
<include name="NativeView.java"/>
<include name="EventBridge.java"/>
<include name="Timer.java"/>
<include name="InternalGPS.java"/>
<include name="NonGPSSensors.java"/>
<include name="KalmanFilter.java"/>
<include name="Settings.java"/>
<include name="SafeDestruct.java"/>
<include name="InputListener.java"/>
<include name="NativeInputListener.java"/>
<include name="DownloadUtil.java"/>
</javac>`
```

What does bootclasspathref and should android.target.classpath be defined else where? I'm new to Adndroid and ant so this may be a problem caused by my lack of knowledge.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Someone has given me the answer which is that the SDK's API has changed. The fragment should now be:

```
- <target name="compile-jni-classes" depends="-setup">
+ <target name="compile-jni-classes" depends="-build-setup">
<mkdir dir="${native.classes.dir}"/>
<javac source="${java.source}" target="${java.target}"
debug="true" extdirs=""
destdir="${native.classes.dir}"
- bootclasspathref="android.target.classpath"
+ bootclasspathref="project.target.class.path"
verbose="${verbose}">
<src path="${src.dir}" />
```